# Override Yii Login Url for Module

Tags: php, yii, yii-modules

How to override Yii Login URL Modul for module?

here is the main configuration for base application:

```
return array(
            .........

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(              
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            'loginUrl' => '/site/login',
        ),
           ..........
      );
```

And then i have agent module, i want in this this module the login URL is different and login method is also different.

```
class AgentModule extends CWebModule {

    public function init() {
        // this method is called when the module is being created
        // you may place code here to customize the module or the application
        // import the module-level models and components
        $this->setImport(array(
            'agent.models.*',
            'agent.components.*',
        ));

        $this->defaultController = 'default';
        $this->layoutPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('agent.views.layout');
        $this->components = array(
            'user' => array(
                'class' => 'AgentUserIdentity',
                'loginUrl' => '/agent/default/login',
            )
        );
    }
            .......
```

But i don't know why this not work.
Please help... (T.T)

Comment: You want to use different user application component for module and app? Or they are same?

Comment: i want to use different user application for module, example: if i in agent module, use agent authentication method which the data is from agent table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2nd code block in your question you defined `user` component for module `AgentModule`.

If i understand right, somewhere in your view or controller you use `Yii::app()->user->loginUrl`, right? To get url defined in `AgentModule` you should use `Yii::app()->user->controller->module->user` but **only** while in `AgentModule` context.

Easiest way to make it different is to define somewhere login urls for module, and for app, and just use this predefined urls.

Try reading about module compoents here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/27/how-to-access-a-component-of-a-module-from-within-the-module-itself/

Comment: Yes, what you explain is right like what i want. Will soon read the link you give and give feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
class AgentModule extends CWebModule {
    public $assetsUrl;
    public $defaultController = 'Login';

    public function init() {

        // this method is called when the module is being created
        $this->setComponents(array(
                'errorHandler' => array(
                        'errorAction' => 'admin/login/error'),
                'user' => array(
                        'class' => 'CWebUser',
                        'loginUrl' => Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/login'),
                )
                )
        );

        Yii::app()->user->setStateKeyPrefix('_admin');

        // import the module-level models and components
        $this->setImport(array(
                'admin.models.*',
                'admin.components.*',
                )
        );
    }

    public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action) {

        if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)) {
            // this method is called before any module controller 
            //action is performed
            $route = $controller->id . '/' . $action->id;


            $publicPages = array(
                    'login/login',
                    'login/error',
            );

            if (Yii::app()->user->name !== 'admin' && !in_array($route, 
                              $publicPages)) {
                Yii::app()->getModule('admin')->user->loginRequired();
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {

    public $module = array();

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        if(isset($this->module['loginUrl'])){
            if(!isset($this->module['moduleId'])){
                throw new Exception('moduleId Must defined');
            }else{
                $moduleId = Yii::app()->controller->module->id;
                if($moduleId == $this->module['moduleId']){
                    #$this->loginUrl = Yii::app()->request->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl($this->module['loginUrl']));
                    $this->loginUrl = array($this->module['loginUrl']);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

```
after that you need to do some changes under config file i.e 
return array(
    'components' => array(
        'user' => array(
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
            'class' => 'WebUser',
            'module' => array(
                'loginUrl' => '/r_admin',
                'moduleId' => 'r_admin'
            )
        ),
    )
);
```